# Invalid expression term => error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2013

My following VS2013, .NET 4.5.1 code (to replace test with Atest) gives the above error:

```
return Regex.Replace("This is test. Another test.", "test", "A" + m => m.Value);
```

But, the following code, to replace test with testA, works:

```
return Regex.Replace("This is test. Another test.", "test", m => m.Value + "A");
```

**Note**: The above example is just for explaining the error. The real regex pattern is more complex.

Comment: This should also work `return Regex.Replace("This is test. Another test.", "test", m => "A" + m.Value );`

Comment: @Tommy Thank you. Could you please add your comment as an answer. I works.

Comment: @sstan The first code example does not work the second one works but the second one would return testA. I need to return Atest. I've just added a Note, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lambda expression:

Before "=>" : They look like InArguments. So you cannot use assignment, operation, logic.. on them

After "=>"  : They look like Expression term

Example :

1. (x, y) => x == y
2. (int x, string s) => s.Length > x
3. () => SomeMethod()